# Show current date in Coupa/Liquid

Tags: liquid-layout

I am trying to show the current date in Coupa. 
I used this code:

```
{% assign today = "now" | date: "%s" %}
```

But it only displays `now` string as output.

Comment: You can use javascript to show current date in Coupa. This will execute in Supplier Print View but not in Preview layout. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Will this be for purchase order templates?  If so, I think you will want to use:

{{ purchase_order.created_date | date: "%Y/%m/%d" }}